# main.cpp|45|error: expected primary-expression before "int" and "double"

Tags: c++, c, compiler-errors

File sys.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

[...]

struct kmph_in_mps
        {
            int kmph[4];
            int result[4];


            void kmph_erfassen()
            {
                for (size_t i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
                {
                    cin >> kmph[i];
                }
            }

            void mps_erfassen(int kmph, double result)
            {
                result = kmph / 3.6;
            }

            void ergebniss_ausgeben()
            {
                cout << endl << kmph << "Km/h sind " <<result << " Meter pro Sekunde\n";
            }
        };

[...]
```

File main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include "sys.cpp"
#include <fstream>

kmph_in_mps c;


[...]


void Kmph_in_mps()
{
    system("cls");
    cout << "\nKm/h: ";
    c.kmph_erfassen();
    c.mps_erfassen(int kmph, double result);
    c.ergebniss_ausgeben();
    t.beenden();

}

[...]
```

Errors:

```
Error: expected primary-expression before “int”
Error: expected primary-expression before “double”
```

I am a learning C++, and I dont get what to do now.
I am searching for answers at the internet and here, but I dont realy find the right one.
Which primary expression do I have to write before "in" and "double"?
Or am I doing everything completly wrong, like a beinner does? :P

Edits:
I tryed return result, but it seems to be not allowed in a void.

I already tryed `c.mps_erfassen();`   but it is gives me an error, too: error: no matching function for call to `kmph_in_mps::mps_erfassen()'|

I already tryed `c.mps_erfassen(kmph, result);` but then I do not declare them both in this scope. They are declared in the other file (sys.cpp). :S

Answer (score 3):

```
  c.mps_erfassen(int kmph, double result);
              //^^^remove int and double
```

When you call a function, you should not put the type before the parameters.

Comment: Sorry forgot to write, edited my post, I also tryed this, got an error, you can see in the post line Edit: the 2. one.

Comment: @Sinmson you need to include proper header files so that the compiler can find the function you called. Make sure function parameter type and order matches.

Comment: I included it with #include "sys.cpp", you can see it in the code top from file.cpp.

Comment: @Sinmson You included the cpp file not the header file. There is a huge difference

Comment: Ok. But how can I include it when #include <sys.h> doesnt work?

Comment: @Sinmson `<sys.h>` is going to include system headers. you may rename it to `sys_test.h` and #include "systest.h". I suggest you read some C++ tutorial

Answer (score 0):

This

```
c.mps_erfassen(int kmph, double result);
```

should be

```
c.mps_erfassen(kmph, result);
```

Let function deduce the type :)

EDITED IN RESPONSE TO COMMENT:-

You are creating object of struct in main.cpp while it's definition is in sys.cpp. How would main.cpp would get to know what your struct means.

For better design, place declaration of struct in header file say sys.h, then define required members in .cpp file say sys.cpp ( you have to include sys.h ). And then use that struct in your main.cpp ( again you have to include sys.h over here ).

Comment: But then kmph and result werent declared in this scope. Because they are declared in the other file (sys.cpp). Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: that's why you're getting problem... Just for testing purpose copy everything from sys.cpp into main.cpp

Comment: I will try, I am sure this will work, but how shell this help?       Tryed it, I was wrong, the error: main.cpp|57|error: no matching function for call to `kmph_in_mps::mps_erfassen(int[4], int[4])'| appered.

Comment: Include it with what syntax? #include "sys.h" is not working